# unpacking GVariant in javascript

Tags: javascript, gobject, gnome-3, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I have an array stored as a GVariant of type `a(ss)` in GSettings, that I want to use in a Cinnamon Applet.  I can retrieve the value successfully using the following code:

```
let schema = schema_source.lookup(SCHEMA_NAME, false);
let settings = new Gio.Settings({ settings_schema: schema });
let my_value = settings.get_value('myvalue');
```

but I can't unpack it.  As far as I can see, I will probably need to unpack it using a `GVariantIter` structure, but the documentation is limited, and I can't find the correct interface in the gjs API (if, indeed, it exists).  Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!

**edit:**
my schema looks like this:

```
<key type="a(ss)" name="myvalue">
    <default>[]</default>
    <summary>an array of (string, string) tuples</summary>
    <description></description>
</key>
```

For the time being I'm using an external `JSON` file to store settings, but it's not a 100% satisfactory solution.  I suppose I could maintain two `as`-type variables, and keep them aligned, but there must be a way to do this properly, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late, but `my_value.unpack()` works absolutely fine.

`my_value.deep_unpack()` will recursively unpack the arrays and their elements.

Comment: Works for me! -- May I ask where you found this piece of information? In the [official docs](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html) I cannot find a method named `unpack()`.

Answer (score 0):

From your type of setting I guess you want to store/retrieve an array of strings? In this case, there is an easier method using [`Gio.Settings.get_strv(String key)`](http://www.roojs.org/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/seed/Gio.Settings.html):

```
// Read the array (will create a real JS array):
let string_array = settings.get_strv("myvalue");
// Now do something with it...
// Store it:
settings.set_strv("myvalue", string_array);
Gio.Settings.sync(); // Important!
```

In your schema, you would then include an entry like this:

```
<key name="myvalue" type="as">
  <default>[]</default>
  <summary>Some array.</summary>
  <description>An Array of strings.</description>
</key>
```

I use the same technique in my extension: [Read/Write](https://bitbucket.org/LukasKnuth/backslide/src/b9a565e6649ea461db4a907ca78c1eada82d656d/backslide@codeisland.org/settings.js?at=master#cl-132) | [Schema](https://bitbucket.org/LukasKnuth/backslide/src/b9a565e6649ea461db4a907ca78c1eada82d656d/backslide@codeisland.org/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.backslide.gschema.xml?at=master#cl-16)

Comment: thanks for your answer.  unfortunately, i need to store an array of _pairs_ of strings, hence `a(ss)`, and hence the problem.  i've update my question a little.