# Gtk.Entry in Gtk.TreeView (CellRenderer)

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject, gobject, gobject-introspection

I want to pack a `Gtk.Entry` (with `Gtk.EntryCompletion` hooked up) into a cell in a `Gtk.TreeView`.  Does anyone know how this can be done?  (I just need entry completion on a text entry in a tabular view.)

Do I perhaps need to subclass `Gtk.CellRenderer` or `Gtk.CellRendererText`, and override the `start_editing` method (or similar)?  I can find examples of subclassing `Gtk.CellRenderer`, but not modifying the editable behaviour.  I can't find the source-code for the `Gtk.CellRendererText` class, either.

I'm using Gobject Introspection (i.e. `from gi.repository import Gio, Gtk, GLib, Gdk`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I finally worked out how to do this.

```
class CellRendererAutoComplete(Gtk.CellRendererText):

    """ Text entry cell which accepts a Gtk.EntryCompletion object """

    __gtype_name__ = 'CellRendererAutoComplete'

    def __init__(self, completion):
        self.completion = completion
        Gtk.CellRendererText.__init__(self)

    def do_start_editing(
               self, event, treeview, path, background_area, cell_area, flags):
        if not self.get_property('editable'):
            return
        entry = Gtk.Entry()
        entry.set_completion(self.completion)
        entry.connect('editing-done', self.editing_done, path)
        entry.show()
        entry.grab_focus()
        return entry

    def editing_done(self, entry, path):
        self.emit('edited', path, entry.get_text())
```

Inspiration dervied from the [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq13.055.htp), and adapted to `pygobject`.

Comment: You, or anybody else coming here, may wish to check out my complete (read, complex) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136209/python-autocomplete-in-an-editable-gtk-treeview-cell/57137888?noredirect=1#comment100791715_57137888), that doesn't need subclassing.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to subclass, GTK+ rarely requires this. It might be more practical in Python (than in C) of course, if so it should be fine.

[This page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK+_By_Example/Tree_View/Editable_Cells#Editable_Text_Cells) shows how to enable editing, by setting the `editable` property to `TRUE`.

You can use `gtk_tree_view_set_cursor()` to move the cursor to a cell and also to start editing programmatically.

Comment: thanks, but I'm aware of all that and it doesn't really address my question at all.  i need to intercept or override the `on_edit` event so that I can modify the behaviour, to hook the `Gtk.Entry` up with completion or replace it with my own, completion-enabled one.

Comment: i found what i was looking for this morning (see my answer).  it think it was a night's sleep that helped, as much as anything, but +1 to you for posting something that made me start thinking about this again this morning :)  thanks!

Comment: i don't suppose you would be able to help with my [other problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736695/unpacking-gvariant-in-javascript), would you?